# Running a batch command without results on screen

Tags: command-line, batch-file, ping

I'm running into an issue while writing a batch file. I wonder if anyone might have a solution for me. This file is very long so I am trying to figure out a way to do less code writing. I have many echo messages that get displayed for a few seconds and then disappear when the file moves on to the next screen/code. I know I can write it something like this...

```
@echo off
echo Message
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
```

Writing `ping localhost -n 3 >nul` every time I want a delay is time consuming. I know I could copy and paste but that is not ideal for my situation either. I had the idea of setting a variable to equal `ping localhost -n 3 >nul` written as,

```
set delay3=ping localhost -n 3 >nul
```

this would allow me to just type `%delay3%` to save time. I found this functionally works fine but it has a side effect. When written this way,

```
@echo off
set delay3=ping localhost -n 3 >nul
echo Message
%delay3%
cls
```

my batch file will display all the ping data on screen even though I've written `@echo off` at the beginning of my script. Just to be clear, this data only shows up on screen when I use the `%delay3%` version of the code. Does anyone know of a way to make the ping data not show up on screen when coding it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I make the ping data not show up on screen when coding it this way?

The problem is with your `set` command:

```
set delay3=ping localhost -n 3 >nul
```

The `>nul` (used to throw away the output) is applied to the `set` command and is not stored in the variable.

On the other hand:

```
set "delay3=ping localhost -n 3 >nul"
```

Does what you want.

Corrected batch file:

```
@echo off
set "delay3=ping localhost -n 3 >nul"
echo Message
%delay3%
cls
rem do other stuff
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
> test
Message

>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm DavidPostill's answer is effective.

Another solution is to escape the "*greater*" sign in the SET command, using the "*caret*" symbol:

```
set delay3=ping localhost -n 3 ^>nul
```

It works the same way for "*pipe*" sign.

Escaping specials characters can be handy in complex command lines, with combination of FOR, IF, FINDSTR ... and error stream must be redirected to NUL or output stream piped to some other command.

One can also use a more versatile version:

```
set wait=ping localhost ^>nul -n
```

and then one can use it with any number of seconds:

```
%wait% 3
some command
%wait% 20
some other command
```